Unable to generate info logs from logic page to the extentreport - specflow c#
I am unable to get logs into extent report. I am here looking for info logs such as Status.Info, from StepDefinition or from logic in page to extent report. I have implemented this in 2019 but now I don't remember the code and I am trying and unable to achieve it please help someone, thanks.
Below is the afterstep hook code:
AfterStep code screenshot
    [AfterStep]
    public void AfterStep(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        var scenario = scenarioContext["extentTest"] as ExtentTest;
        ScenarioBlock scenarioBlock = _scenarioContext.CurrentScenarioBlock;
        var exception = _scenarioContext.TestError;
        if (null == exception)
        {
            var CostToUseData = MarkupHelper.CreateTable(costToUseData);
            //var Test = _scenarioName.
            var mediaEntity = _driverHelper.CaptureScreenshot(_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title.Trim());
            switch (scenarioBlock)
            {
                case ScenarioBlock.Given:
                    scenario?.CreateNode<Given>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text);
                    break;
                case ScenarioBlock.When:
                    scenario?.CreateNode<When>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text);
                    scenario?.CreateNode<When>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Log(Status.Info, "Testing extent logs 2");
                    break;
                case ScenarioBlock.Then:
                    scenario?.CreateNode<Then>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text);
                    break;
                default:
                    scenario?.CreateNode<And>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (null != exception)
        {
            var mediaEntity = _driverHelper.CaptureScreenshot(_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title.Trim());
            switch (scenarioBlock)
            {
                case ScenarioBlock.Given:
                    scenario?.CreateNode<Given>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Fail(_scenarioContext.TestError.Message, mediaEntity);
                    break;

                case ScenarioBlock.When:
                    scenario?.CreateNode<When>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Fail(_scenarioContext.TestError.Message, mediaEntity);
                    break;

                case ScenarioBlock.Then:
                    scenario?.CreateNode<Then>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Fail(_scenarioContext.TestError.Message, mediaEntity);
                    break;

                default:
                    scenario?.CreateNode<And>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Fail(_scenarioContext.TestError.Message, mediaEntity);
                    break;
            }
        }
        Logger.Log.Info(ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title);
        //_scenarioName = _scenarioName?.CreateNode<Scenario>(_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title, _scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Description);
    }

Your assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Please do not post images of code. Instead, copy and paste the code into your question. You can use the { } icon to format the code.

https://github.com/harshitwadaskar007/Harshit_Wadaskar-SSEAIRTRICITY

This is the project git path, I am unable to add log.info in the report

Including a link to the GitHub project is fine, but we need you to [edit] your question to include a [repro].

Added afterstep code so here I dont remember what should I write to include log.info into the extentreport, please help

That is better, but please indicate the error in your post as well.

there is no error, its just I want the script to get log.info into my extentreport

Can you please clarify what you are trying to accomplish? You had a screenshot showing a syntax error in Visual Studio, so you clearly tried something. Can you add that code to the question, and include what the error was in Visual Studio?
